# how to configure s3 bucket to allow aws application load balancer (not class) use it? currently throws' access denied'

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, amazon-elb, terraform-provider

I have an application load balancer and I'm trying to enable logging, terraform code below:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "lb-logs" {
  bucket = "yeo-messaging-${var.environment}-lb-logs"
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_acl" "lb-logs-acl" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.lb-logs.id
  acl    = "private"
}


resource "aws_lb" "main" {
  name                       = "main"
  internal                   = false
  load_balancer_type         = "application"
  security_groups            = [aws_security_group.public.id]
  enable_deletion_protection = false
  subnets                    = [aws_subnet.public.id, aws_subnet.public-backup.id]

  access_logs {
    bucket  = aws_s3_bucket.lb-logs.bucket
    prefix  = "main-lb"
    enabled = true
  }
}
```

unfortunately I can't apply this due to:

```
Error: failure configuring LB attributes: InvalidConfigurationRequest: Access Denied for bucket: xxx-lb-logs. Please check S3bucket permission
│       status code: 400, request id: xx
```

I've seen a few SO threads and documentation but unfortunately it all applies to the classic load balancer, particularly the 'data' that allows you to get the service account of the laod balancer.

I have found some policy info on how to apply the right permissions to a SA but I can't seem to find how to apply the service account to the LB itself.

Example:

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "allow-lb" {
  statement {
    principals {
      type        = "AWS"
      identifiers = [data.aws_elb_service_account.main.arn]
    }

    actions = [
      "s3:GetObject",
      "s3:ListBucket",
      "s3:PutObject"
    ]

    resources = [
      aws_s3_bucket.lb-logs.arn,
      "${aws_s3_bucket.lb-logs.arn}/*",
    ]
  }
}


resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "allow-lb" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.lb-logs.id
  policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.allow-lb.json
}
```

But this is all moot because `data.aws_elb_service_account.main.arn` is only for classic LB.

---

EDIT:

Full code with attempt from answer below:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "lb-logs" {
  bucket = "yeo-messaging-${var.environment}-lb-logs"
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_acl" "lb-logs-acl" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.lb-logs.id
  acl    = "private"
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "allow-lb" {
  statement {
    principals {
      type        = "Service"
      identifiers = ["logdelivery.elb.amazonaws.com"]
    }

    actions = [
      "s3:PutObject"
    ]

    resources = [
      "${aws_s3_bucket.lb-logs.arn}/*"
    ]

    condition {
      test     = "StringEquals"
      variable = "s3:x-amz-acl"

      values = [
        "bucket-owner-full-control"
      ]
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "allow-lb" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.lb-logs.id
  policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.allow-lb.json
}


resource "aws_lb" "main" {
  name                       = "main"
  internal                   = false
  load_balancer_type         = "application"
  security_groups            = [aws_security_group.public.id]
  enable_deletion_protection = false
  subnets                    = [aws_subnet.public.id, aws_subnet.public-backup.id]

  access_logs {
    bucket  = aws_s3_bucket.lb-logs.bucket
    prefix  = "main-lb"
    enabled = true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The bucket policy you need to use is provided in [the official documentation for access logs on Application Load Balancers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-access-logs.html).

```
{
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Principal": {
        "Service": "logdelivery.elb.amazonaws.com"
    },
    "Action": "s3:PutObject",
    "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/prefix/AWSLogs/your-aws-account-id/*",
    "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
            "s3:x-amz-acl": "bucket-owner-full-control"
        }
    }
}
```

Notice `bucket-name` `prefix` and `your-aws-account-id` need to be replaced in that policy with your actual values.

---

In Terraform:

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "allow-lb" {
  statement {
    principals {
      type        = "Service"
      identifiers = ["logdelivery.elb.amazonaws.com"]
    }

    actions = [
      "s3:PutObject"
    ]

    resources = [
      "${aws_s3_bucket.lb-logs.arn}/*"
    ]

    condition {
      test     = "StringEquals"
      variable = "s3:x-amz-acl"

      values = [
        "bucket-owner-full-control"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mark -- but not exactly sure how to translate this into a terraform definition, will give it a shot and get back

Comment: @SebastianG I added the Terraform code to my answer

Comment: Thanks Mark, just ran that and unfortunately it's still throwing the same error: `Please check S3bucket permission
│       status code: 400`

I have updated my question to include the full code

Comment: Are you sure the ALB is in a public subnet? A subnet with a route to a Internet Gateway? This is why I suggested on another of your related questions to try creating an EC2 instance in the same subnet as the ALB for testing, because it is starting to look like the ALB is in a private subnet without a route to anything outside the VPC.

Comment: It might be more productive at this moment to look at your AWS VPC flow logs (enable them first if you haven't already) to determine if traffic is getting to your load balancer, and possibly see in there if traffic from the load balancer to S3 is failing at the network level also.

Comment: Initially it 100% wasn't and requests were timing out because of it, I mentioned there the outcome of that session -- ended up adding the NAT/routing tables, I can now see in the monitor that my requests are indeed going to the load balancer

Comment: A public load balancer shouldn't be behind a NAT.

Comment: That was for the private subnet in the VPC, I was throwing everything at the wall to see what sticks. 

I have enabled flow logs for the VPC and it works, I'm seeing only lines ending in `REJECT OK` for 10.0.0.52 - 10.0.0.4 and 10.0.0.12, I'll check if these are in my public CIDR

Comment: I've been able to re-build from scratch with a VPC split in a more coherent way and also include the fargate service in both subnets unfortunately the logs still fail with the exact same permissions error and it makes little to no sense at this stage after 70+ hours dumped into this

Comment: what logs? Also, have you considered using something like this: https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-aws-modules/vpc/aws/latest instead of trying to build everything from scratch?

Comment: The access_logs on the load balancer can't be added due to "access denied for bucket", I've read the documentation several times to the letter for both AWS and terraform and a dozen SO threads, no clue why permission is still an issue, it really shouldn't be. 

I'll look into that module, but at this stage the VPC config itself looks ok and I'm assuming the `503` is occurring because of the task configuration somewhere/somehow.

Comment: To enrich this answer, the bucket policy and terraform depends on the region and type of zone as of August 2022, re: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/enable-access-logging.html#attach-bucket-policy

Answer (score 3):

**TL:DR** Ensure that the bucket policy is created and attached to the bucket *before* creating the load balancer or updating its logging configuration.

The issue you are experiencing may be caused by the incorrect order in which the resources are being created.

When logging is initially enabled for a load balancer, AWS will write a test file to the designated bucket. If this process occurs before applying the (correct) bucket policy, the attempt will fail.

When creating the load balancer, bucket, and bucket policy simultaneously, the load balancer and bucket policy will depend on the bucket. However, the load balancer will not be recognized as a dependency of the bucket policy. In certain cases, especially when adding the logging configuration to an existing load balancer, the test file writing may occur before the bucket policy has been applied.

Answer (score 1):

The current method for enabling an ALB to write access logs to S3 involves using the ELB service account as the principal in the policy document. Using `"Service": "logdelivery.elb.amazonaws.com"` no longer seems to work to allow an Application Load Balancer to write logs to the S3 bucket. The ELB service account can be retrieved using the `aws_elb_service_account` data source in Terraform.

Here is a simple example:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "logs" {
  bucket = var.bucket_name
}

resource "aws_lb" "svc" {
  name               = var.lb_name
  load_balancer_type = "application"
  security_groups    = [aws_security_group.lb.id]
  subnets            = [aws_subnet.public.id]

  access_logs {
    enabled = true
    bucket  = aws_s3_bucket.logs.id
  }
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "lb_logs" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.logs.id
  policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.lb_logs.json
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "lb_logs" {
  statement {
    principals {
      type        = "AWS"
      identifiers = [data.aws_elb_service_account.lb.arn]
    }
    actions   = ["s3:PutObject"]
    resources = ["${aws_s3_bucket.logs.arn}/*"]
  }
}

data "aws_elb_service_account" "lb" {}
```

I hope this helps the next person who comes across this question while researching the same issue.